# How do I combine hyperref and classicthesis without errors using (dvi)latex.

Tags: hyperref, dvi, classicthesis

I'm trying to get this document to work using the latex command.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{classicthesis}%
\begin{document}
\chapter{Intro}
\label{chap:intro}
\end{document}
```

I keep running into the following error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-ppl.cfg)
Chapter 1.
! Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
\@uclclist ->\oe 
                 \OE \o \O \ae \AE \dh \DH \dj \DJ \l \L \ng \NG \ss \SS \th...
l.7 \chapter{Intro}
```

I know it's the combination of hyperref and classicthesis that causes this, but I don't know a good way around it other then disabling hyperref. Does anybody have an elegant way to make this example work?

Comment: You should load **hyperref** after **classicthesis**.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but unfortunately it gives the same error.

Comment: I get no error with `pdflatex`; **classicthesis** is not really compatible with `latex` (dvi output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`classicthesis` loads the package hyperref by using `pdflatex`. By `latex-ps-pdf` the packages decides not to load hyperref and to disclaim some features.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{subfig}

\let\myoldchap=\chapter
\usepackage{classicthesis}%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\tocEntry}[1]{% for bib, etc.
 \texorpdfstring{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{#1}%
    }


\renewcommand*{\chapter}{\secdef{\Chap}{\ChapS}}
\renewcommand\ChapS[1]{\myoldchap*{#1}}%
\renewcommand\Chap[2][]{%
    \myoldchap[\texorpdfstring{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{#1}]{#2}%
         }


\begin{document}
\chapter{Intro}
\label{chap:intro}
\end{document}
```

The order is very important. First save the *orig-chapter* before loading `classicthesis` which also redefines `chapter`

Comment: Great, this works.